# How to generate a list which contains a given number of random numbers within a range in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, random

I know how to generate a single random number within a given range, a list of random numbers, a list which contains a given number of random numbers but NOT a list which contains a given number of random numbers within a RANGE. Can anyone help me on this?

This code (extracted from haskell.org) generates a list of 10 random numbers, but I need to give a range, any ideas on how to edit this to give a range?

```
import System.Random
import Data.List

main = do
 seed  <- newStdGen
 let rs = randomlist 10 seed
 print rs

randomlist :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomlist n = take n . unfoldr (Just . random)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
randomList :: (Random a) => (a,a) -> Int -> StdGen -> [a]
randomList bnds n = take n . randomRs bnds
```

Using [`randomRs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#v%3arandomRs) from `System.Random`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this code gave an error as: 

Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : randomList
*** Type          : RandomGen a => (a,a) -> Int -> StdGen -> [a]
*** Given context : RandomGen a
*** Constraints   : Random a

Comment: @PraveenieNilakshikaPerera: The constraint is wrong. It should be `(Random a) => ...` instead of `(RandomGen a) => ...`.

Comment: @PraveenieNilakshikaPerera: whoops, fixed :s (that's what I get for quickly copying the usage off of the haddock docs but forgetting that the seed is class-based as well :s)

Comment: @ivanm can you please tell me how to call this function? I thought it's "randomList (10, 100) 10 seed" but it doesn't work, sorry I'm a noob :/

Comment: You can also use randomR: `randomList n = (take n .) . unfoldr . (Just .) . randomR`

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to call this function?

Comment: @PraveenieNilakshikaPerera using that works for me; what error do you have?

Comment: @PraveenieNilakshikaPerera `randomList (lowBound, highBound) listLen someGen`. The type signature ivanm provided for `randomList` should guide you in using it.

Comment: I had to do the following: let g = mkStdGen 42
 let rs = randomList (0 :: Int, 256 :: Int) 10 g

Answer (score 5):

[quickcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.4.2) can also be used to generate random numbers and has in fact really nice combinators that make it more understandable to formulate a generator.
To use it you just need to import one module:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
```

Defining the generator can then be done as:

```
t :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> Gen [Int]
t n r = vectorOf n (choose r)
```

To run this generator you can make use of `sample'`:

```
randomList n r = head `fmap` (sample' $ t n r)
```